# How to view MCA Minecraft Region Files as Text. How do programs like mcedit and others work to read mca files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to read contents mca files, not random obfuscated stuff that show up when I a text editor to open it.

Comment: Hi Unknown Axis, there are two questions in your title: can you specify what exactly you are looking for? And what do you mean with "random obfuscated stuff" if that's not what you intend to make? .mca files are written in a certain programming language (Java, C++, or other), so just opening them in a text editor will make them appear unreadable (for humans), so you need software that can 'translate' it to something that makes sense for us. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would also accept a program that converts mca files to code too.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a programming question. It belongs to potentially [so] or [gamedev.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MCAs are all stored in NBT notation, which has JSON and binary serializers alike for it.

You can find details about the [NBT File Specification](https://wiki.vg/NBT) here.